# Android studio creating new intent

Tags: java, android

I find myself trying to create a new intent to use it for switching activities in my android app using the android studio IDE.
However, I get an error saying cannot resolve constructor when I try to do so.
Here is what my code looks like.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Where Menu.class is another java class empty activity

Comment: Whats a `Menu` here ? add it with question .

Comment: Menu is the java file name for  just  another activity created as an empty activity.

Answer (score 2):

You could call `postDelayed(@NonNull Runnable r, long delayMillis)` method instead. Like below:

```
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Menu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        },0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have imported wrong menu class. Just import the one you made and it will fix this error.
**How I came to this conclusion ?**
Android has Menu class inbuilt , so you must have imported that class. which will throw this error.

It is a good practice to add Activity after the name of activities. for example : `MenuActivity`

Answer (score 0):

if you use explicit intent, make your code like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: The intent has worked but My startActivity call says it cannot be resolved.

Comment: The startActivity() method starts an instance of the DisplayMessageActivity that's specified by the Intent. Next, you need to create that class.

[https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You can also make intent in single line,

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Menu.class));
      }
    },1000);
```